# How to propagate configuration everywhere with dart sass modules (@use, @forward, etc..)?

Tags: css, sass, libsass, dart-sass

I'm trying to migrate from libsass (`@import`) to dart sass modules (`@use, @forward`).

Honestly, I'm finding it quite difficult, because a lot of mixins and files (modules) i used, depend on general configuration variables.

In libsass it was all simple, but now variables are strictly scoped to original modules. You can pass along modules with `@forward`, and you can use `with()` to pass variables to a module, ok.

But I used to have a big website configuration.scss file, which defined essetially global variables used both in subsequent local @imports as well as in external 'framework' @imports.

THis system doesn't work anymore. I need a way, is available, to propagate some variables globally, always available. Can't find new best practices in this direction.

Comment: take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62805040/global-css-variables-without-import